# Вопрос по js и размещению картинок в html

Tags: javascript, html, css

Здесь разместил полностью работу, которую выполнял по практической, но её самой поэтапной сейчас нет рядом, к сожалению: https://repl.it/join/welwyeor-rodrik
Интересуют вопросы по ней:

1. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]Как сделать в полную длину изображения и при этом оставить между ними разрыв?
2. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]Также прописал скрипт, но он не рабочий из-за чего-то, хотя в css по нему данные также вписал, но он он не работает, подскажите, как можно исправить? И как убрать ту область, которая налезает на кнопку "Back to top"?
3. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]Как возможно убрать тот промежуток?
   Заранее благодарю за любой ответ и помощь.

Answer (score 0):

1. Попробуйте блоку в котором лежат эти картинки задать

```css
.block {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

или margin и padding.

2. Кнопке можно задать z-index: 1; Но это так себе решение, потому что я не вижу полного кода.
3. Нажмите F12 и нажмите эту кнопку,[image: введите сюда описание изображения] и после наведите на блок, который вас интересует, и смотрите, что там происходи с отсупами

Comment: Хорошо, по 1 и 3 попробую сделать те способы. Вы имеете в виду, что не видите сам код js? Он там в отдельном файле прописан, также в css по нему прописано.